# Python Asyncio help.... Am I doing this right?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Program listens to a websocket. When a certain message is received, we need to wait 5 seconds then run a restapi call out to another server.

It works with a single websocket message that I am able to manually trigger. However, there will be a high volume of websocket messages that I will be processing around ~50-100 messages per second. Not sure If I am going about the right method or not. I hope asyncio is the right tool for the job too or if I should do something with threads.

Also, Do i need "result = await on_message(msg)" or "result = on_message(msg)" in the ws_connect function? I am completely new to asyncio

Thanks in advance....

```
async def do_long_process(id):
        # Need to wait 5 seconds before doing anything
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        return requests.post('http://do.action.com/%s', id)



async def on_message(message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    if msg['type'] == 'takeaction':
        response = await do_long_process(msg['id'])



async def ws_connect():
    uri = f'ws://server/ws'

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            result = await on_message(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(ws_connect())
```

Answer (score 1):

Asyncio is the right tool for this job, you don't need threads, but you do need to switch from requests to an asyncio-compatible http library, such as aiohttp.

> Do i need "result = await on_message(msg)" or "result = on_message(msg)" in the ws_connect function?

Since `on_message` is `async def`, you need either `await` or `asyncio.create_task()`. If you need to wait for the result, you await. Otherwise, you call `asyncio.create_task(on_message(msg))` and let it run in the background.